# Allow query params globally

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I have multiple routes with possible subroutes. The routing works as expected, however I would like to globally (on all routes) allow certain (or all) query parameters.

e.g. http://example.com/route/match?utm_source=test and http://example.com/route?utm_source=test... should work, is there a way to allow this on all my routes, or should I add a Query subroute for every route?

Example of current routes:

```
'category' => array(
    'type'    => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/:category[/]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'category' => '[a-z][a-z0-9-]*',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller'    => 'Category',
            'action'        => 'index'
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'subcategory' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
            'route'    => ':subcategory[/]',
            'constraints' => array(
                'subcategory' => '[a-z][a-z0-9-]*',
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller'    => 'Category',
                'action'        => 'subcategory'
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Edit:
I just noticed that if a route has no child_routes defined, the query parameters are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters are always allowed, regardless of the query route. It was merely meant for assembling, which was deprecated as of ZF 2.1.4 thought.